Combinatorics - Counting possible combinations of ordered set with conditions
While trying to brush up on my maths I have stumbled upon the following combinatorics problem :
"Imagine that the world has 24 time zones (evenly spaced around the globe) and
that a class has exactly one student in each time zone.
How many ways are there to form 12 partnerships (2 students each) if you insist
that each student’s partner live in a timezone where the time differs by at most 2
hours (ignoring date)" (source is 18.600 fall 2023 problem set 1).
I am pretty much stuck on this problem.
I have tried to break the problem into 3 smaller ones : counting number of pairs between students with 1 hour difference (2 possibilities), counting number of pairs with 2 hours difference (2 possibilities) and counting the rest of the possibilities (?), but couldn't solve the last one.
I also tried to look at what happened based on the first pair : what happens if student $k$ is paired with $k-2$, or $k-1$... but didn't find any lead.
I would really appreciate any help I could get !

To get started:  Look at the possible gaps between consecutive pairs.  If $(1,2)$ are partnered, then of course $(3,4)$ might be as well.  But $(4,5)$ can't be and neither can $(5,6)$ (unless $(3,4)$ are).  If $(1,2)$ are partnered and $(7,8)$ is the next consecutive pair, then we must have $(3,5)$ and $(4,6)$ as partners.  And so on.

@lulu Seems reasonable, but also seems to surrender the problem to brute force.  For example, what if there were $~50~$ people and $~50~$ time zones?

Clarification requested: So, timezone-1 can partner with timezone-k, where $~k~$ is any element in $~{23,24,2,3}.~$  Have I interpreted the problem correctly?

@user2661923  Same method should work.  The gaps between consecutive pairs are tightly restricted.  You can have blocks of four (possibly more than one block of four), in the manner I sketched, but that's it.  I may be over simplifying a bit, but I think you can arrange $n$ blocks of $4$ and $m$ blocks of $2$, where of course $4n+2m$ equals the total number of time zones, however you like, and that's it.

@user2661923  To stress: I didn't think through all the details, just the core idea.

@lulu Being totally ignorant of graph theory, I can't help but wonder if graph theory would yield a more elegant approach.

@user2661923 Yes exactly !

To complete the sketch discussed in the comments:
Key Idea:  There are two obvious sorts of blocks we can have, namely consecutive pairs and consecutive groups of $4$ grouped as $ABAB$. To specify a solution, we just to describe the partnership block that $1$ is in and then look at the choices from there.
We start by noting that a zone $i$ can only be paired with one of $i\pm 1, i\pm 2$, writing the zones cyclically (so $1-2=23$ for example).  For the case $(i, i+2)$ we remark that $i+1$ can only be paired with $i-1$ or $i+3$. And similarly, for $(i-2, i)$ we must have one of $(i-3, i-1)$ or $(i-1, i+1)$  Thus every zone $i$ is either a member of one of the  $2-$blocks $(i-1,i)$ or $(i,i+1)$, or it is a member of one of the four $4-$blocks $$(i-3, i-1)(i-2, i)\quad (i-2, i)(i-1, i+1) \quad (i-1, i+1)(i, i+2) \quad (i, i+2), (i+1, i+3)$$
And of course this pattern recurs.  The end of one block must start a new block, and there are only $2-$blocks and $4-$blocks to choose from.
Suppose there are $n$ $2-$blocks and $m$ $4-$blocks.  Then $2n+4m=24$.  We see that $m\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5, 6\}$ so there are $7$ choices for the pair $(n,m)$. We consider each in turn.
$(n,m)=(0,6)$.  Picking the $4-$block $1$ belongs to determines the rest, so $\boxed 4$.
$(n,m)=(12,0)$ Picking the $2-$block $1$ belongs to determines the rest, so $\boxed 2$.
$(n.m)=(2,5)$.  Choose the block that $1$ is in.  At the clockwise end of that block we choose the next type, $2$ or $4$ and so on. There are $7-1=6$ choices to be made.  If $1$ is in a $2$-block ($2$ cases) then exactly one of those choices is the other $2-$block, so there are $\binom 61=6$ ways to make choices.  Thus this case gives us $2\times 6 =\boxed {12}$ solutions.  If $1$ is in a $4-$block ($4$ cases) there are still $2$ pairs left so there are $\binom 62=15$ ways to choose, thus $4\times 15=\boxed {60}$ solutions.  So, in total $60+12=\boxed {72}$
That is the general computation. If we have $(n,m)$  with neither $n,m=0$ then there are $2\times \binom {n+m-1}{n-1}$ cases in which $1$ is in a $2-$block and there are $4\times \binom {n+m-1}n$ cases in which $1$ is in a $4-$block.
This is easily automated and we see that  the number of solutions as $m$ runs from $0$ to $6$ is $$[4,72,210,224,108,24,2]$$
And the final answer is the sum:  $$\boxed {\bf {644}}$$
It should be obvious, but to stress:  This computation, while not exactly difficult, is somewhat tedious and error prone, so I suggest checking it carefully.
Note that, once the logic is established, the main computation is easy enough and could easily be extended to more time zones.  It's just a sum of binomial symbols in the end.

Thanks a lot, its way more clear now !
